# XML and NavigationView Positioning

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer, toolbar, drawerlayout

I have made a layout in which I have created a toolbar of my own in XML and I have set the Navigation View according to my requirement. I want that after clicking the hamburger icon the topleft  , navigationView content should be displayed along with the back button on the topleft. I am able to make the content in the navigation View Visible but not the back button. Because the Navigation View is overlapping on my toolbar and the back button gets behind or underneath the navigation view. I am not getting the way to sort this out in XML. help me in this situation.

Code for the XML layout is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/dl"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.loveb.demo_viewpager.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            >
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tablayout"
        android:id="@+id/pager">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/navview"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_layout"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"
        >
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must set toolbar in an other parent layout test below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/dl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.loveb.demo_viewpager.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tablayout">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_layout"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"> 
  </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```